# Customize JWT token to add userId in Spring authorization server 1.0.0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, spring-authorization-server

I am new to spring security and spring authorization server. I wanted to customized the JWT access token to include additional parameter of userId within token generated.

I am using spring-authorization-server 1.0.0 and OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter is final class, hence unable to override it.  Can someone guide me on which class needs to be configured or how this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [`OAuth2TokenCustomizer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/core-model-components.html#oauth2-token-customizer) in the reference. It gives access to the claims of the JWT before it is built, so you can customize however you need to.

Note that if you want to customize a specific token, this component is passed the `context.getTokenType()` so you can add an if-statement to only customize the `access_token`. See [How-to: Customize the UserInfo Endpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/guides/how-to-userinfo.html#customize-id-token) for an example (which customizes the `id_token`).

---

**Update:**

In order to add a dynamic value (such as a `userId`), you obviously would need to get the value to add. You might access the `Principal` associated with the authorization to do this, as in the following example:

```java
@Bean
public OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> tokenCustomizer() {
    return (context) -> {
        if (OAuth2TokenType.ACCESS_TOKEN.equals(context.getTokenType())) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = context.getPrincipal();
            User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();

            context.getClaims().claim("userId", ((CustomUser) user).getId());
        }
    };
}
```

This assumes you created a `CustomUser` with an `id`.

If you need to look up a value, it's no different than any other Spring application. You should inject the bean you need to perform the lookup:

```java
@Bean
public OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> tokenCustomizer(CustomRepository repo) {
    return (context) -> {
        // ...
    };
}
```

How you use the injected bean is up to you. There are additional methods on the `context` such as `context.getAuthorization()` (returns the `OAuth2Authorization`) to get more context about the current authorization if needed.

Comment: Thanks  I am able to add static key value pairs and its coming in jwt token generated. Is there any way to pass dynamic values? I want to include userId in the access token.

Comment: I added some examples.